# Execute commands on machine after ssh login

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line, expect

I want to run some commands on another machine after I logged in through ssh. I have automated login using expect. I don't know much about bash and expect. Please help me out.
Here is what i have written:

```
spawn ssh user@ip
expect "password:" { send "mypassword\n"}
interact
echo yes
```

Comment: Obligatory suggestion: use public-key authentication to automate `ssh` logins, not `expect`.

Comment: If you want to use Expect, I'd recommend you put some effort in to actually learn it. *Then* come back here when you have **specific** questions.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to execute a single command on the remote server, you can send the command in single quotes like: `ssh user@ip 'echo "yes"'`

But if you want multiple commands to be run, then its better to use telnet than ssh.

Comment: Telnet is insecure. If you want to execute multiple commands, use some automation software like Puppet or Ansible.